# Unable to retrieve users with multiple tags from Quickblox

Tags: ios, objective-c, quickblox

I'm trying to retrieve users that have multiple tags from Quickblox, like in this example below:

> User 1 tags: aaa, bbb, ccc
>   User 2 tags: aaa, ccc, ddd
>   User 3 tags: aaa, ccc
>   User 4 tags: aaa, ddd
>   User 5 tags: aaa, bbb, ccc
>  
>   User 6 tags: aaa, bbb, ccc

Using the code below:

```
NSArray *tags = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"aaa", @"bbb", @"ccc", nil];

[QBRequest usersWithTags:tags page:[QBGeneralResponsePage responsePageWithCurrentPage:page perPage:1000] successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBGeneralResponsePage *pageInformation, NSArray *users) {
    NSLog(@"pageInfo: %lu", (unsigned long)pageInformation.totalEntries);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < [users count]; i++) {
        QBUUser *tU = [users objectAtIndex:i];
    }


} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
    // Handle error

    NSLog(@"resp: %@", response);

}];
```

Quickblox retrieves only users 1, 5 and 6 with this. So I figured, it will only deliver me the users that have those exact tags I'm sending. But I was wondering if there is any way, making solely 1 call to Quickblox that would retrive every user that has each of these tags. In this example, all the 6 users have tag "aaa", therefore every user should be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. At this time the method to retrieve users with tags use logical operator AND.

A feature to retrieve users with tags using OR operator has been planned for the next releases.

Comment: When will it be released? Do you have an estimate?

Comment: At this time there is no ETA.